# How to have ruby-debug-ide running together with normal rails server by default, not waiting for remote connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I followed [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/How+to+setup+and+run+ruby+remote+debug+session) guide and my debugging working just fine; however, at first the debugger just waits forever until an IDE connect to it, before it starts a normal rails server.

```
vagrant@acme:~/workspace/ror-starter$ docker-compose up app-dev
rorstarter_db-dev_1 is up-to-date
Starting rorstarter_app-dev_1 ... 
Starting rorstarter_app-dev_1 ... done
Attaching to rorstarter_app-dev_1
app-dev_1       | Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234
```

I would like to have it running just like normal by default, and stop for debug whenever there is a remote connection connecting to it and a break point set in the IDE.

Is there any way?